# Can I use Timer Input capture interrupt and GPIO interrupt on same line?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, timer, interrupts

I use Timer Input Capture of [STM32L476RG](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c5/ed/2f/60/aa/79/42/0b/DM00108832.pdf/files/DM00108832.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108832.pdf).Is it possible if a timer capture based on interrupt will disable normal EXTI interrupt on the same line? For example TIM2_CH1 can be input capture on PA0. Does it mean I cant use PB0 as a normal external interrupt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible if a timer capture based on interrupt will disable
>   normal EXTI interrupt on the same line?

As far as I know, it won't be disabled, both interrupts will be generated according to your timer and EXTI configuration. You can e.g. configure the timer capture interrupt to catch rising edges, and EXTI to catch falling edges.

If both are configured to act e.g. on rising edges, then both interrupt handlers will be called, one after the other. Priority levels in `NVIC` will decide which interrupt handler runs first, and the other is called immediately when the first handler returns.

> For example TIM2_CH1 can be input capture on PA0. Does it mean I cant
>   use PB0 as a normal external interrupt?

**You can use both pins at the same time as interrupt sources.**

The source for `EXTI0` is selected by the `SYSCFG->EXTICR1` register bits 0-2. If you write `001` (binary) to these bits

```
SYSCFG->EXTICR1 = (SYSCFG->EXTICR1 & 0xFFFFFFF80LU) | 1;
```

then `EXTI0` will be connected to `PB0`, and `PA0`, `PC0` etc will be ignored by EXTI.